# Return tuple of list in recursion function

Tags: python

I am learning Python's recursion. I define a linked list where each node has item and next. I want to write a recursion to put odd and even number in a seperate set.

```
class LinkNode(object):
"""A node in a linked list."""

def __init__(self, item, next=None):
    """(LinkNode, object, LinkNode) -> NoneType
    Initialize this node to store item and next.
    """
    self.item = item
    self.next = next

def odd_or_even(self):
    """(LinkNode) -> ([object], [object])
    Return a pair of lists: (odd number, even number.
    """
    if self is None:
        return ([], [])
    else:
        if (self.item % 2 == 1):
            odd_num = odd_num.append(self.item)
        else:
            even_num = even_num.append(self.item)
    if self.next is not None:
        self.next.odd_or_even()
    return (odd_num, even_num)
```

When I run it, i got the following error:

File "C:\Program Files\Wing IDE 101 4.1\src\debug\tserver_sandbox.py", line 19, in odd_or_even
builtins.UnboundLocalError: local variable 'odd_num' referenced before assignment

Where should i initial odd_num, even_num so it won't be overwritten?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are a few different approaches you could use.

One would be to use global variables. I don't really recommend this, but it is easy to understand, so I'm presenting it first:

```
even_num = [] # these should be at module level, but I'm not showing the class
odd_num = []  # so you'll have to imagine the indentation being correct

def odd_or_even(self):
    """(LinkNode) -> ([object], [object])
    Return a pair of lists: (odd number, even number.
    """
    if self.item % 2 == 1:
        odd_num.append(self.item)
    else:
        even_num.append(self.item)

    if self.next is not None:
        self.next.odd_or_even()
```

The changes to the code are minor, mostly just removing `return` statements. I did take out the initial check for `self` being `None`, as that's never possible in a method (unless the caller tries very hard to make it happen). It's also worth noting that we do not attempt to assign to `odd_num` or `even_num` directly, as that would create a local variable, rather than accessing the global variables that already exist. The downside of this solution is that you can only call `odd_or_even` once and have it work properly. If you want to call it again (perhaps on another list) you need to reinitialize global variables.

Here's a better approach, which creates even and odd lists as local variables, and then returns them at the end. This is probably what you were aiming for in your code, but you were missing the step of adding the results of the recursive call onto the list.

```
def odd_or_even(self):
    even_num = []
    odd_num = []

    if self.item % 2 == 1:
        odd_num.append(self.item)
    else:
        even_num.append(self.item)

    if self.next is not None:
        next_even, next_odd = self.next.odd_or_even()
        even_num.extend(next_even)
        odd_num.extend(next_odd)

    return even_num, odd_num
```

The problem with this code is that creating and extending lists is wasteful. On each level of the recursion, two new lists will be created, even though only one value is going to be handled at that level. A better approach can use just two lists total, for the whole recursive process:

```
def odd_or_even(self, lists=None):
    if lists is not None:
        even_num, odd_num = lists
    else:
        even_num = []
        odd_num = []

    if self.item % 2 == 1:
        odd_num.append(self.item)
    else:
        even_num.append(self.item)

    if self.next is not None:
        return self.next.odd_or_even((even_num, odd_num))
    else:
        return even_num, odd_num
```

This is more efficient than the previous version, since it uses the same list on all levels of the recursion. In some other programming languages, this style of recursion, where all the work is done before the recursive call is run, is much more efficient than other kinds of recursion. This is because a compiler can optimize away the `return` step of the function (and just reuse the stack frame). However, Python doesn't do such "tail call optimization" (because it would mess up stack traces) so the benefits are not as big as they might be.

Another thing to think about: You could use your own linked-list class, rather than Python lists to hold the even and odd values. Both the second and third solutions I showed above could work, though the third would work most naturally if you were willing to have the even and odd values returned in reverse order.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I tested the code using the local variables you suggested, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (self.item % 2 == 1):
        odd_num = odd_num.append(self.item)
    else:
        even_num = even_num.append(self.item)
...
return (odd_num, even_num)
```

The above section of code sets the value of either `odd_num` or `even_num`, but not both.  It then attempts to return both `odd_num` and `even_num`, which produces an error for one or the other.  If you initialize both to `None` just before that `if` statement, you'll avoid the error that occurred.  However, to make the semantics work, you may need to add another parameter to your function, namely the result from the previous level; in the recursive call, pass the just-computed `odd_num` or `even_num` down to the next level; then return the result of the next level down.  However, it might be better to avoid recursion and instead have a loop that runs twice.